# all doctrine migration alter same table and no change in db

Tags: symfony, doctrine, database-migration

On symfony 4.3 (doctrine 2.10)

all migrations contain the same lines, even without entity changes...

example:

> ALTER TABLE file_master CHANGE file_name file_name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL')

do you have the same issue?

Tkx.
Cédric

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with mariadb database. I changed database version in doctrine.yaml file and it worked for me:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
       server_version: 'mariadb-10.4.7'
```

I took server version from phpMyAdmin. Before this value was '5.7'

Comment: ..or `mariadb-10.4.8`. But it also works by specifying simply `8.0`, derived from MySQL versioning

Answer (score 0):

This might be linked to this particular issue : https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/3006 in Doctrine.

One workaround that seem to work is to make sure that if any of your entity's field has an `option` parameter containing `default`, it should be equal to `1` like this, and not be just a key (`options={"default"}`):

```
@ORM\Column(name="field", type="integer", length=8, options={"default": 1 })
```

See https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/6845

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, but not work. E have now: 'ALTER TABLE file_master CHANGE file_name file_name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT \'1\'');

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MariaDB here is an article about that issue: https://marenkay.com/post/symfony-doctrine-mariadb/

I've solved it by simply removing server_version from the doctrine config completely. Otherwise you have to specify the mariadb version, for example "mariadb-10.3.18" instead of the mysql version.